# Jasmine test the javascript function for url

Tags: javascript, url, testing, jasmine

Here is my code:

```
var getCode = function(code) {
if (code = (new RegExp('[?&]' + encodeURIComponent(code) + '=([^&]*)'))
        .exec(location.search))
    return decodeURIComponent(code[1]);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
var code = getCode("code");
//some other function
```

and here is my test code:

```
 it("check the code value of url", function() {
    window.location.search = "https://test.com?&code=testParam";
    var code = getCode("code");
    expect(code).toEqual("testParam");
});
```

Whenever I try to run this as jasmine test it shows runtimeexception or says hte variable getCode is not defined. Is there anyway I can set the location url and test it?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it little differently.
Dont take the url from browser. rather pass the url as an argument to the function. This way you can hardcode a url and send it to test.

```
var getCode = function(code, url) {
    if (code = (new RegExp('[?&]' + encodeURIComponent(code) + '=([^&]*)'))
    .exec(url))
  return decodeURIComponent(code[1]);
};
```

And run the test something like below.

```
it("check the code value of url", function() {
var url = "https://test.com?&code=testParam";
var code = getCode("code", url);
expect(code).toEqual("testParam");
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I want to get the url of current page. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: You can only get the url of the page which is having the jashmine test case while running it (using window.location.href).

Comment: Got it. But still it shows can't find variable getCode in my test case in the spec. Is there any reason that it is not reading this variable?

Comment: You have to refer to the js file in the top of the jashmine test page which is having the funtion defination, Means below code.
var getCode = function(code, url)

Comment: I put the var getCode at the top of my js file but still it says can't find variable

Comment: I am getting * ReferenceError: Can't find variable: getCode in the Spec file

Comment: Now I am getting expected undefined when I call var code = getCode("code", url);